# Translate pipe is not working in child module

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, ngx-translate

I am developing a sample app using Angular 8. Along with ngx-translate for translation. 
I have imported all the required code in app.module.ts for translate service and it worked perfectly fine. As soon as i added a new module for lazy loading and trying to access the translate pipe in this newly created module, it is giving me error

> The pipe 'translate' could not be found

Can anyone please help?

Comment: hey, can you share a bit of code :) ? maybe a stackblitz ?

Comment: its too much of code, still i will try.. I think, i am missing something really basic step here.

Comment: try to make a minimal replication of your issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing **TranslateModule** in child module's **module.ts** worked.
Thanks guys.